# Android Wear library problems with deploying to device (OK in emulator)

Tags: android, shared-libraries, wear-os

I’m trying to run a standalone wearable application on a (physical) wear OS device, running Oreo 8.1. The application builds successfully and runs fine on an Android Wear square emulator (API 26) but when I try and run the application on the physical device, I am receiving the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find wearable shared library classes. 
Please add <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.wearable" android:required="false" /> to 
the application manifest
```

As the error code instructs, the line

```
<meta-data. android:name="com.google.android.wearable". android:value="false" />
```

has already been added to the application manifests file (AndroidManifest.xml) inside the application tag. Shown below is the application tag’s contents in the manifest file.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="false"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
    android:value="true" />

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.wearable" android:required="false" />

<activity android:name="com.example.android.wearable.wear.alwayson.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Even with the suggested line added to android manifest file, I continue to receive the exact same error code.

I suspect the version of the library on the device isn't the same as what our development environment is using, however I don't know how to find and check the device library version.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this issue?

Build Info:

```
compileSdkVersion 28

buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

defaultConfig {
  versionCode 1
  versionName "1.0"

  minSdkVersion 24

  targetSdkVersion 27

  multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {

  implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.0.0'
  implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'

  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.0.0'

  compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.1.0'

  implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.1.0'
 }
```

It was suggested in the comments that I change from `compileOnly` to `implementation`. Here is the error message received:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.wearable.wear.alwayson, PID: 2593
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.wearable.wear.alwayson/com.example.android.wearable.wear.alwayson.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
        at com.google.android.wearable.compat.WearableActivityController$AmbientCallback.<init>(WearableActivityController.java:6)
        at androidx.wear.ambient.WearableControllerProvider$1.<init>(WearableControllerProvider.java:52)
        at androidx.wear.ambient.WearableControllerProvider.getWearableController(WearableControllerProvider.java:51)
        at androidx.wear.ambient.AmbientDelegate.onCreate(AmbientDelegate.java:103)
        at androidx.wear.ambient.AmbientModeSupport.onCreate(AmbientModeSupport.java:198)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2414)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1418)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1335)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7019)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

There doesn't seem to be a lot of online information about setting up and developing for Android Wear, so any pointers on useful resources will be appreciated.

-------- Updated 6th April based on new testing

In the original post I only showed the application tag of the manifests file. Outside of the application tag did contain the line:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />`

The use of the outdated libraries simply due to using the provided (outdated) samples that came with the source package for the device . Originally I had followed the tutorial provided by google (same link as you provided which uses wearable:2.5.0) and was unsuccessful – returns same error stated in the original post.

I did try multiple sample apps contained at the location you provided, before I posted on SO, as well as samples provided within the source package for the development kit – all results in the same error.

Here is the full error code that was posted originally. This occurs when the device tries to the launch the app.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.wearable.speaker, PID: 3230
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.wearable.speaker/com.example.android.wearable.speaker.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find wearable shared library classes. Please add <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.wearable" android:required="false" /> to the application manifest
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find wearable shared library classes. Please add <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.wearable" android:required="false" /> to the application manifest
        at androidx.wear.ambient.SharedLibraryVersion.verifySharedLibraryPresent(SharedLibraryVersion.java:57)
        at androidx.wear.ambient.WearableControllerProvider.getWearableController(WearableControllerProvider.java:48)
        at androidx.wear.ambient.AmbientDelegate.onCreate(AmbientDelegate.java:103)
        at androidx.wear.ambient.AmbientModeSupport.onCreate(AmbientModeSupport.java:198)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2586)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:838)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
        at com.example.android.wearable.speaker.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:254)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1335)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7019)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I checked the code in which the exception is being thrown and apparently it’s due to a lack of a precense holder for the shared library it is trying to verify the existence of. Below is the function in the file “SharedLibraryVersion.java.”

```
/**
 * Throws {@link IllegalStateException} if the Wearable Shared Library is not present and API
 * level is at least LMP MR1.
 * <p>
 * <p>This validates that the developer hasn't forgotten to include a {@code <uses-library>} tag
 * in their manifest. The method should be used in combination with API level checks for
 * features added before {@link #version() version} 1.
 */
public static void verifySharedLibraryPresent() {
    if (!PresenceHolder.PRESENT) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find wearable shared library classes. "
                + "Please add <uses-library android:name=\"com.google.android.wearable\" "
                + "android:required=\"false\" /> to the application manifest");
```

From this it looks as though the wearable library isn’t on the device, or is but can’t find/link it?

As per Martin's comment, suggesting that if wearable apps from the playstore can run then the lib should exist on the device, I tried to install some wearable apps. The sdk verison on the dev kit doesn’t have a play store, so I tried sideloading some  I found online via adb.

Whilst adb returned success when runnig “adb install appname.apk” none of the apps actually appeared except one, APKPure, which is an app sideloader itself that runs on the device. Trying to install wearable apps via APKPure on the dev kit also didn’t work as I receive “install/uninstall actions not supported on Wear”. This seems to be due to the PackageManger blocking the installation of arbitrary APKs - looks like a dead end.

Comment: Can you share which is the physical device running on Wear OS? Manufacturer/Model

Comment: What if `compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.1.0'` was changed to `implementation 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.1.0'`?

Comment: We are using a Qualcomm Snapdragon wear 2500 device. The module is made by Intrisync out of Canada.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - coronavirus delays at work. Regarding the change from compileOnly to implementation, I get the error message added to the bottom of the original post (too big for a comment)

Comment: At a dead end at the moment, I can't think of anything else to try. Suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Create a Wear OS app](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating) hints for, that you miss one node, which does not belong into the `application` node:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```

As well as, that you are using outdated libraries:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.5.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.5.0'
}
```

And based upon the other values, that should be:

```
targetSdkVersion 28
```

---

If it doesn't work, try running any of the [`wear-os-samples`](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples) for a comparison.

If wear apps from the Play Store would find it, one can assume it is available on device.

---

In case you are using the [Open-Q™ 2500 Development Kit](https://shop.intrinsyc.com/collections/product-development-kits/products/open-q-2500-development-kit), you might have to flash another firmware. The [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192711%20status:open) is for the component itself, which most likely does not apply here; better contact Intrinsyc Technologies Corporation [support](https://www.intrinsyc.com/support) department.

Comment: A firmware for wearable should provide package `com.google.android.wearable`. This dependency is just `compileOnly`, so that all classes will be already known at compile time. During run-time it then links against the one which the firmware provides.

Comment: Hi Martin, we have hit a dead end - see the updates to the original question for more information on the troubleshooting we have done. Any further help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to get the com.google.android.wearable installed on the Open-Q development kit? Is another firmware needed or this can be resolved with build options of the app?